# Cardinalities in er diagrams

Tags: cardinality

What is the difference between (0,n) and (1,n) cardinalities and how to distinguish them in a given situation .
For example, given integrity constrains , and you have to design an er diagram. I know that first of all i should define the cardinalities for each entity and relationship.

Comment: One is required and one isn't.

Comment: What do you mean? Both are required i just don’t know which one to use in different cases.

Comment: That's literally the difference. You use whichever one is appropriate for the situation. If you can have zero of something, you use 0,n. If you **must** have at least one, you use 1,n. I'm unsure which part you're having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you, the problem is i can’t distinguish when “ i must have at least 1, and when it can be 0” if you have link to any source where this topic is explained , please share. Thanks again)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your mini-world. for example, in a company, there should be no department without at least one employee. in another company, it is allowed to have a department without  any employees related to that deparment.